# Stop APEX code at a certain line

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

How can i stop APEX from executing the code at a certain line,

For example:

In C we have

exit(-2);

In Fortran we have

Stop

Whats the the equivalent command in APEX

Answer (score 1):

I Just used :

```
System.assert(false);
```

and it does what I want,

Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0):

If you are on visualforce page controller return null in pagereference method will stop the execution at that point.If you are on trigger add error method or throwing custom exception message will stop execution.There is a break statement that helps to exit form the loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop running a method just put `return;` or `return null;` if you are in a method which returns a value.